# Trasforming a system of rational equations into an equivalent system of polynomial equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, rational-functions

Suppose that a system of rational equations $r_1=0, r_2=0, \dots, r_m=0$ defines a zero dimensional variety $V$.

Is there an algorithm to produce polynomials $p_i$, starting from the rational functions $r_i$, such that the polynomial system $p_1 = 0, p_2 = 0, \dots, p_n = 0$ defines the SAME zero dimensional variety $V$?

All of the functions involved can be considered in $\mathbb{C}^k$ for some $k \ge 1$.

EXAMPLE:

Let $r_1 = x^2 - 1, r_2 = \frac{x y}{x-1}$. The naive thing I would do would be to take the numerators of each $r_i$, that way I get $p_1 = x^2-1$ and $p_2 = x y$. This system of polynomial equations defines $y=0, x = \pm 1$, while the system of rational defines $y=0, x = -1$.

Comment: but this is not an algorithm to go from the $r_i$ to the $p_i$, because there is no algorithm to solve for the equations in general

Comment: There is an algorithm to determine the $\{(x_i,y_i)\}$, by the Tarski-Seidenberg theorem

Comment: Could you elaborate more? It seems like you are saying that there is an algorithmic way to find the roots of a rational system, in particular you could the algorithmically find the roots of an arbitrary high degree polynomial which I thought was impossible. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem)

Comment: The Abel–Ruffini theorem concerns solvability in *radicals*. It has nothing to do whatsoever with algorithmic root finding.

Comment: I see. Well, then I could perhaps change the question in "what are the algorithms to go from r to p"

Comment: What you do is add equations that force the denominators to be non-zero.  For example, if you add $r_3$ and the equation $r_3(x-1) = 1$, this rules out the $x = 1$ solution.

Comment: I think there exists no such an algorithm in the multivariate case. At least, the [Kronecker software](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~lecerf/software/kronecker/doc/getstarted/getstarted.html) aimed at solving system of polynomial equations and non-equalities treats the latter separately.

Comment: arsmath, make it an answer and I will accept it. It's clearly the thing to do